# Adding include paths to a CLion Makefile project

Tags: c, makefile, include, clion, jetbrains-ide

Upon researching this issue, all of the questions talk about adding include paths into the `CMakeLists.txt` file, however none seem to mention a way for `Makefile`s.

How should I do it, besides the obvious approach of switching to CMake?

Answer (score 1):

For Makefile, you should use `CPPFLAGS` or `CFLAGS` to add include search path, e.g. in Makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/my/folder
```

Comment: Will it get detected by CLion though? The issue in my case is that CLion doesn't detect the include path, thus returning errors about a header file not found.

Comment: Did you try Google?  It very quickly led me here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/project-models.html and here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/makefiles-support.html

Comment: clion seems doesn't add the cpp flags -I/{dir} into include path